# Curve Fitting and Multiple Experiments

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation, estimation

Say I do an an experiment 5 times, each of which gives you a list of data points. Do I fit a curve to each one separately and then average the parameters and their uncertainties? Or do I take the average of all the experiments and then do fit a single curve to that?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that each data point brings information. Since each of them is in error, treat all the data points in the same regression.